# PayPal Smart Payment Buttons - Status when processing

Tags: button, paypal, callback, status

I'm testing PayPal Smart Payment buttons and have been using some functions or callbacks to know certain status, like `createOrder()`, `onApprove()`, `onCancel()`, `onError()`.

I need to know (in code) when the PayPal form/iframe/control starts processing the payment (when it shows the loader). It's like some callback before `onApprove()`. Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an `onInit`, and (most interesting to you), an `onClick` that is called when a button is clicked: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/validation/